# How to get pictures from the flickr API

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, flickr

My goal is to bring in photos based on a search of 5 different words; 5 photos each word. I need to bring the pictures back into my site; preferably smaller versions as I will bring many files in.

I am new to rest services in general. I saw this option:

https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html

and I go to the API explorer link at the bottom:

https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photos.search

and put in 猫 (meaning cat) for the text field and number of pictures per page at 5 and pages 1, so I would only get back 5 images. This gives me this XML link:

https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=4aa062c1cd2da6075e27b599f583665a&text=%E7%8C%AB&per_page=5&page=1&format=rest&api_sig=9f1beab3f0da8f620e197104eb81aa2a

My question would be what would I do with this request? It looks like it is giving ample information to be able to locate each image, but how would I use this XML to pull the images directly into my site?

Comment: why do you need to work with this api if you don't know what to do with the request?

Comment: What I need is to send a search out for a Chinese character the user asked for and get back just the images and there aren't really a lot of services out there that can do that without charging a fair amount (considering I'll be pulling down 20 images per search and we will have several classrooms of students use this). I have no idea if this will be able to do what I need but I am taking it one step at a time. I want to avoid scraping images because right now there is no backend or DB and if I can avoid that it would be nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

shellwe --

After making the request, you'll need to use the information returned to you and build the 'Photo Source URL' (see: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html)

In essence, you'll want to loop through the response and build the photo url.

As an example, using the first line item provided in your link:

```
https://farm{farm-id}.staticflickr.com/{server-id}/{id}_{secret}.jpg
```

would be:

```
https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4218/35419029800_7a39f756be.jpg
```

How you incorporate the final photo urls into your website ultimately depends on how you've got things set up.

Hope this helps some.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. I did end up figuring out the answer a while ago but I never got back to report it here. But seeing there's 88 visits, it is good someone did!